# jQuery UI dialog increasingly calling the submit callback

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, jquery

I took the JQuery UI dialog form sample from JQuery UI website.

Since I wanted that, once the dialog is opened and the form is displayed, that pressing the  key submits the form, I added the following in the onReady() :

$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, { 
      open: function() {
          var $this = $(this);

```
      // focus first button and bind enter to it
      $this.parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').focus();
      $this.keypress(function(e) {
          if( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
              $this.parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').click();
              return false;
          }
      });
  }
```

});

This does perfectly the trick (I mean the click() is triggered when it has to), but the following occurs :

When the form is first submited through a press on the  key, the submission is performed once.

If I reopen the dialog, and submit it again with a press on the  key, the form is submitted twice.

If I reopen the dialog, and submit it again with a press on the  key, the form is submitted three times, and so on...

This can be tested with the following fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/fWW2E/

Let me add that doing so by clicking on the dedicated "Submit" button works properly, this fails only when pressing the  key is involved.

Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because since you're assigning this on "open" and your buttons are "closing" the dialog.

When this gets called though:

`$('something').dialog('close');`

doesn't actually remove the element, it just hides it.  So the next time you click to open up a "new" dialog, you're really just showing the first one again.  However the "open" event is getting fired again every time it's opened, which is adding a new keypress handler onto it.

Here's the fiddle.  I actually write out to the console an array of the current handlers on that element.  You'll see everytime you open the dialog that there is another keypress handler.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fWW2E/1/)

Comment: Pff, feeling so dumb now. Thank you ;) Replaced "open" by "create" indeed did the trick.